# If $\gamma_n$ are roots of $\tan x = x$ can every function be expanded in form of $\sum_n a_n \sin(\gamma_n x)$?

Tags: real-analysis

Solving a linear PDE, I got the general solution $$f(x,t)=\frac{e^{-t/\tau}}x\sum^\infty_{n=1}a_n\sin(\gamma_n x)$$ where $\gamma_n$ is the nth positive root of $\tan x=x$.

To satisfy the initial condition we require
$$\phi(x)=\frac1x\sum^\infty_{n=1}a_n\sin(\gamma_n x)$$

From a physical point of view, $\phi(x)=f(x,0)$ represents the initial temperature profile of the object, which can be arbitrarily defined. Hence, I assumed such a expansion form is possible for most sufficiently well-behaving $\phi(x)$, but I cannot prove it.

> What are the necessary and sufficient conditions for expanding a function $\phi(x)$ into $\frac1x\sum^\infty_{n=1}a_n\sin(\gamma_n x)$?

Noteworthily, $\gamma_n\sim\frac{\pi}{2}+n\pi$ thus this series is ‘almost’ a Fourier sine series.

When this expansion turns out to be mathematically possible, how could one extract the $a_n$s? One possible way is performing fourier transform on both sides, so that
$$\int^\infty_{-\infty}x\phi(x)e^{-i\omega x}dx = \sum^\infty_{n=1}a_n\delta(\omega-\gamma_n)$$ assuming $\omega>0$, but often does one have knowledge of $\phi(x)$ only on a physically meaningful region $[0,a]$.

Comment: It seems that the function must be able to be approximated using the sum of odd functions.  An even function such as cosine can't be expanded this way

Comment: @Moko19 Yes, that's true. In the real setting, $\phi(x)$ is only known on the physically meaningful region $[0,a]$ so the problem of oddness is not a problem - we can oddly extend $x\phi(x)$ to the negatives.

Answer (score 1):

The functions $x$ and $\sin(\gamma_j x)$ with $\tan(\gamma_j) = \gamma_j$, are orthogonal on the interval $[0,1]$.  Suitably normalized, I think we get an orthonormal basis of $L^2[0,1]$
(and I think this can be obtained from Sturm-Liouville  theory).  Thus for any square-integrable function $f$ on $[0,1]$, we should have the expansion
$$ f(x) = c_0 x + \sum_{j=1}^\infty c_j \sin(\gamma_j x)$$
(converging in $L^2$) where $$ c_0 = 3 \int_0^1 f(x) x\; dx,\ c_j = \frac{2}{\sin^2(\gamma_j)} \int_0^1 f(x) \sin(\gamma_j x)\; dx$$

Comment: If $f(0)\neq0$ the sum of the series should be discontinuous in $0$?

Comment: The series converges to $f$ in the $L^2$ sense, but not necessarily pointwise everywhere.  The sum of the series is of course $0$ at $x=0$, so if $f(0) \ne 0$ it is not converging to $f$ at $x=0$.  Similar phenomena can be observed with ordinary Fourier series.

Comment: How would you prove the orthogonality?

Comment: Do the integration explicitly and substitute $\sin(\gamma_j) = \gamma_j \cos(\gamma_j)$.